# Giving AnnotationSessionFactoryBean in applicationContext.xml and Tomcat error: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: spring, hibernate

To integrate spring and hibernate I added the sessionFactory bean into the applicationContext.xml.

Intitally I used **org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean** and given the mapping resource as test.hbm.xml file.

Now I want to use the annotated entity class as mapping resource. For that I have changed the sessionFactory class to **org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean**.

### applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

<property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
       <value>org.droidaceapps.contractortimeflow.User</value>           
   </list>
</property>


<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>        
  </props>
</property>
```

But Tomcat is throwing the below exception,

```
 **Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class**
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2823)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1655)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2002)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:561)
```

Is something I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found the error since ? I am having the same problem.